# Django RemoteUserBackend Not Cleaning Username

Tags: python, django, authentication

From the [instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/auth-remote-user/), I have successfully activated django's remote user authentication (see associated snippet below from `SETTINGS.py`).  Active Directory is being used for remote authentication.

```
# snippet from SETTINGS.py
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    ...
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
```

As expected, when a user logs in for the first time, because the user doesn't exist yet, django will create the user.  However, when the user is created, the user's `username` field has a `<domain>\<username>` format (e.g. `"Domain1\PersonA"`).

In an attempt to remove `domain` from `username`, following django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend.clean_username), I have updated the `clean_username()` method within the `RemoteUserBackend` class:

```
def clean_username(self, username):
    return username.split('\\')[1]
```

But, newly created `user` objects still have the `username` incorrectly set to the `<domain>\<username>` format.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do like

```
class MyRemoteUserBackend(RemoteUserBackend):
    def clean_username(self, username):
        return username.split('\\')[1]
```

Then

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'path.to.MyRemoteUserBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
```

Comment: I tried this (placing `MyRemoteUserBackend`, as defined above, in the same file as `RemoteUserBackend` - i.e. `django.contrib.auth.backends` but received an import error: `Module "django.contrib.auth.backends.MyRemoteUserBackend" does not define a "MyRemoteUserBackend" attribute/class`

Comment: "django.contrib.auth.backends.MyRemoteUserBackend" is incorrect. You have to put your path where you defined MyRemoteUserBackend. Do it inside any of your app/mybackend.py. Then it will be `app.mybackend.MyRemoteUserBackend`

Comment: Gotcha, that worked.  I guess I'm not sure why I can't just place the custom backend in the same location as the rest of django's backends.  Many thanks.

Comment: What file do you put the `class MyRemoteUserBackend` into?